# gas estimation error because of reverted

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-limit, gas-estimate, out-of-gas

here is a situation I have: a user came to my platform to buy mytoken and he paid 44 matic for it and 266,087 | 263,663 (99.09%) which reverted because of the gas out. is there any solution to add gas for the user to handle it in a high activity time to not revert becuse of gas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the necessary gas at the time you create the transaction. It appears that you know in advance how much gas will be needed: `266_087`. So you put this value when creating the transaction. If this is in Javascript, typically, you would enter it alongside the other parameters.

- Use `gas` if you use the [`sendTransaction` function](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction).
- Use `gasLimit` if you use the [`sendSignedTransaction` function](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction).

Comment: actually, you are correct but I found another way to solve it. Thanks for your tip.

Comment: It would be worthwhile that you add an answer to your own question with your solution. Other people may hit the same error.

Comment: I wasn't completely sure if my initial solution was the most efficient, but I decided to tweak things a bit on the front end. I added a cool step where we estimate the gas before the front end makes the contract call. Plus, I threw in an extra 10 units of gas before the contract call – just to be on the safe side and prevent any unexpected reverted reasons.

Comment: That's good. Add that as your answer with the "Add Another Answer" button.

Answer (score 0):

I added a cool step where we estimate the gas before the front end makes the contract call. Plus, I threw in an extra 10 units of gas before the contract call – just to be on the safe side and prevent any unexpected reverted reasons